# Adding up the numbers read with BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to get the mean of 20 numbers in my scores.txt file, but I can't figure out how to do it. Every time I try, my output gets all messed up. Thoughts?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
    FileNotFoundException {

    String file ="/Users/vienna01pd2016/Desktop/scores/src/scores/scores.txt";
    processFile("/Users/vienna01pd2016/Desktop/scores/src/scores/scores.txt");
    //calls method processFile
    }


    public static void processFile (String file)
    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    String line;
    //lines is declared as a string


     BufferedReader inputReader =
       new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader
(new FileInputStream(file)));

     while  (( line = inputReader.readLine()) != null){

      //System.out.println(line);
      double Value = Double.parseDouble(line);
     System.out.println(Value);
```

Comment: What does messed up mean?  Can you post the output of the program and the file input

Comment: This is the output I'm receiving...0 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - BigInteger(long) has private access in java.math.BigInteger
 at bigintegerfactorial.BigIntegerFactorial.factorial(BigIntegerFactorial.java:38)
 at bigintegerfactorial.BigIntegerFactorial.main(BigIntegerFactorial.java:15)
/Users/vienna01pd2016/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 10 seconds

Comment: thats an EXCEPTION and not a output.
BigIntegerFactorial.java:38  this shows where the problem is, check line number 38 of BigIntegerFactorial.java

Answer (score 0):

If you have one number on each line, I would read each line using the BufferedReader, put it in a list as well as adding it to a number, then you can divide the total by the amount of numbers in the list:

```
package Testers;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MeanGetter {

    public static ArrayList<Double> ls = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String filepath = "/Users/vienna01pd2016/Desktop/scores/src/scores/scores.txt";
        double total = processFile(/*new File(filepath).getAbsolutePath()*/ filepath);
        double mean = total / ls.size();
        System.out.println("mean: " + mean);
    }

    private static double processFile(String path) {
        double n = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
            String line;
            while  (( line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                double d = Double.parseDouble(line);
                n = n + d;
                ls.add(d);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;


    }

}
```

Comment: It is worth saying that if your application is run in the same location as the scores.txt, you can just do `new File(scores.txt).getAbsolutePath();`